# Android Application Google Map GetLastLocation

Tags: android, google-maps, userlocation

I developed an application using android studio. I used Google Maps in my application. When opening Google maps first I want the last location of the user using the code block below.

```
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
     Location lastlocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

But user last location return null. How can I fix that problem?

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: I got some problem when I use my phone like emulator..